# How to OpenGL detect 3D cube six side colors

Tags: android, opengl-es

> I done 3D cube with different color for all sides. if i rotate means i
>   want to detect which are the colors are focused or which are the
>   vertices focused, get colors are i focused.
>
> > for example,   now i saw 3 sides means i want to get 3 colors. how to
> >     get use openGL.

Comment: Please ! Make an effort !

Comment: k i will but i am struggled. help me

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you'd like to detect, which sides of the cube are visible. You can achieve this with simple math.

For each face:

- get face normal: cross product cp = (v1-v0)x(v2-v0)
- get face to camera vector: cf = c - v0
- get dot product: dp = cp*cf
- if dp>0 then face is facing the camera, so the face is visible.

More info and some real code can be found here: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Backface_culling

Comment: The above answer for android